# Avoid repeating navigation through controllers iOS

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uitableview, segue

I have a (X)UITableViewController's ViewTable linked with another(Y) ( PrototypeCells Table). The PrototypeCells have the selected index on. I created a push-segue onSelected(Y) back to the (X)UITableViewController to make automatic the back button. But this is not exactly what i wanted to reach because it entered in a loop where each time I select something the previous field are deleted.

That's not exactly what I mean saying that i want onSelect(Y) to come back to previous Controller(X).

Comment: This question is pretty difficult to understand. Perhaps you could provide some code and a more concrete step by step description of what is happening versus what you would like to happen?

Comment: I'll try. e.g. in an information table there's the birth place as tab. clicking on that there's the switch between controllers.Now i select my city (with checkmark) from the list. I want to come back to the information table without click on back button in the nav bar and keeping information already written on the information table such as First Name.